# ¿JPA/MySQL definir Zona horaria para tipo TIME?

Tags: java, mysql, spring

Tengo una aplicación con front-end en AngularJS y back-end en Java, usando Spring.

Técnicamente tengo el modelo de la aplicación hecho con JPA, mi atributo conflictivo es el siguiente:

```
@Column(name = "hora_inicio")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
private Date horaInicio;
```

`horaInicio` es una columna en mi tabla (`MySQL` por cierto) que sólo contiene **hh:mm:ss**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al momento de realizar un registro nuevo para esta tabla tengo el siguiente JSON

```
{  
    "a":"dsfsdfdsfsdfsdf",
    "hora":"07",
    "minuto":"00",
    "b":3,
    "c":2,
    "e":1,
    "horaInicio":25200000,
    "id":"140",
    "sh":9999,
    "co":"SOE"
}
```

En el JSON **horaInicio** es un tiempo en milisegundos resultado del calculo de los atributos **hora** y **minuto**, esto lo compruebo con el siguiente script, para ver que las transformaciones internamente se están realizando bien

```
<script>
    var x = "09:15:00";
    var arr = x.split(":")
    var hour = arr[0] * (3600 * 1000);
    var minute = arr[1] * (60 * 1000);
    var second = arr[2] * 1000;

    var answer = hour + minute + second;
    document.write("ms " + answer)

    //inverso: ms a hora

    var h = (answer - minute - second) / (3600 * 1000);

    if(h < 10)
        h = '0' + h; 
    document.write(", hora " + h)

    var m = (answer - hour - second) / (60 * 1000);

    if(m < 10)
        m = '0' + m;
    document.write(", minuto " + m)

    var x = (answer - hour - minute) / 1000;

    if(x < 10)
        x = '0' + x;
    document.write(", segundo " + x)

</script>
```

Este script lo pruebo en [jso.do](http://js.do/).

Bien, el problema es que la hora que se envía desde es el formulario no es la misma que se almacena en la base de datos. Por ejemplo, si a nivel de formulario (front-end) defino la hora **07:00:00** en la base de datos se almacena la hora **02:00:00**. Supongo que la distorción del dato se produce en el momento en el que el `Controller` recibe el JSON y lo parsea a mi `POJO`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/maintenance/", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { "application/json" })
public String save(@RequestBody Planificacion p) {
    try {
            logger.info("INPUT DATA >>> Hora de inicio desde formulario {}", p.getHoraInicio());
            // ....
        }
}
```

La salida del log en ese momento es la siguiente

```
INPUT DATA >>> Hora de inicio desde formulario Thu Jan 01 02:00:00 COT 1970
```

La zona horaria del equipo es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resultado de ello, se extraen 5 horas de la fecha original (07:00:00 - 5 horas = 02:00:00)

Para `JPA` existe alguna forma de definir estrictamente la zona horaria para un atributo `@Column`?

Hago la pregunta porque no es una opción definir desde el arranque (JVM) la zona horaria, ya que la JVM es compartida por otras aplicaciones.

¿De qué manera puedo solventar este detalle a nivel de código sin afectar la JVM?

Comment: java.util.Date por si mismo no tiene timezone. Tienes dos opciones usar un Calendar o definir el timezone que vas a usar en el parser json.

Answer (score 1):

La causa es compleja y no trivial en su solución. El origen está en JDBC.

**Soluciones**

1.- En hibernate 5.2 es posible forzar el uso de UTC time zone utilizando la siguiente configuración.

```
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.time_zone" value="UTC"/>
```

2.- Tal y cómo indican en [ésta página (en inglés)](http://in.relation.to/2016/09/12/jdbc-time-zone-configuration-property/) se puede arrancar la JVM con el siguiente parámetro, con lo que al ser al forzar la zona horaria a UTC, no habrá desviación

```
java -Duser.timezone=UTC
```

**Recomendación**

En general es una buena práctica almacenar y tratar los tiempos siempre en UTC, y utilizar únicamente la hora local para presentación al usuario. Ello evita muchos problemas cuando el software debe manejar distintas zonas horarias simultáneamnete o bien se va a ejecutar dicho softare en diferentes zonas.

Comment: A esto añadiría el familiarizarse con NTP y mantener todos los servidores sincronizados. Idealmente, con una misma configuración para no andar manipulando los datos de una capa a otra o que un despliegue específico no funcione por configuración del OS